# How to programmatically know when a user cancels an in-app subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have implemented in-app purchase in my app but how to known users cancel subscription programmatically.

I want to call API when a user cancels the subscription.

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: @Phantomaxx help

Comment: Google keywords: `android in-app purchase unsubscription check`. It should help.

Comment: I would suggest checking the inventory every time you launch your app, at that time if the inventory returns you null value, then the user has cancelled the subscription. You can add a boolean value in sharedpreference for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Subscriptions and In-App purchases status API, which is a part of Google Play Developer API v2.0.

It allows you to track all the in-app purchases and subscriptions by different users.

A simple request would let you know about the status of the user's subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I run the following code every time the app is launched.

```
        billingClient.queryPurchases( BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS );

    Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases( BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS );
    if (purchasesResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        ArrayList<String> skus = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( getResources().getStringArray( R.array.array_subs_sku ) ) );
        for (String sku : skus) {
            setFlag( mContext, sku + KEY_SKU_PURCHASED, false );
        }

        for (Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {

            setFlag( mContext, purchase.getSku() + KEY_SKU_PURCHASED, true );
            setFlag( mContext, FLAG_SUBSCRIBED, true );
            getIsSubscribed(); // check here if subscription status has changed
            //Log.d( TAG, "onPurchaseHistoryResponse: SUBS" + purchase.getSku() + " / " + getDateStampString( String.valueOf( purchase.getPurchaseTime() / 1000 ) ) + " / State : " + purchase.getPurchaseState() );
        }
    }
```

let me know if you need more help with this. But it should be pretty straight forward. My code has some of my own functions and variables, but it will give you the idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: how to do this for billing library 5.0? any updates for that?